# How to close passCodeScreen after entered a correct password in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am want to close the passcode screen after I enter the correct password. Here is my code. I separated my code into 3 files.
this is my code in the passcode_bloc. This code I using for processing entered passcode

```
import 'dart:async';

class PasscodeScreenBloc {
  String isValidPasscode = "123456";

  final StreamController<bool> verificationNotifier =
      StreamController<bool>.broadcast();

  void onPasscodeEntered(String enteredPasscode) {
    bool isValid;
    isValid = isValidPasscode == enteredPasscode;
    verificationNotifier.add(isValid);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    verificationNotifier.close();
  }
}
```

this is my code passcode_state.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:passcode_screen/passcode_screen.dart';
import 'passcode_screen_bloc.dart';

class passcodeScreenPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return passcodeScreenPageState();
  }
}

class passcodeScreenPageState extends State<passcodeScreenPage> {
  String title = "Enter you pass word";

  PasscodeScreenBloc passcodeScreenBloc = PasscodeScreenBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PasscodeScreen(
      title: Text("Enter you pass word"),
      passwordEnteredCallback: passcodeScreenBloc.onPasscodeEntered,
      cancelButton: Text("Cancel"),
      deleteButton: Text("Delete"),
      shouldTriggerVerification: passcodeScreenBloc.verificationNotifier.stream,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      isValidCallback: () => {},
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    passcodeScreenBloc.verificationNotifier.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

I was trying to watch to example code in the [link](https://pub.dev/packages/passcode_screen). Almost as the same. It run but not close. [image: my screen]

Comment: does it display any error? Can you share how you open `passcodeScreenPage`?

Comment: It's not an error. This display opens as soon as I open this app. I want this to disappear when I input true password

Comment: the plugin works in such a way that when the password is correct the view closes. That is, you have to have behind it another view that you have opened before.